# Reference request for texts on causation

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-physics, causation

I have been very interested in causation lately. I am especially interested in whether it can be defined at all, or it must be taken as a brute fact. I would love to read some texts on causation, and see what philosophers have said about it, about possible definitions of it, how it relates to physics, etc. I want to see some references.

Comment: A good start would be the [IEP article](https://iep.utm.edu/causation/) and then follow up the references.

Comment: Causation is taken as fact before Hume, Hume considered it as unjustifiable, Kant considered it as a category of understanding, modern physicalism can take it as given based on observed laws

Comment: [Causation in Physics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causation-physics/) and [The Metaphysics of Causation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causation-metaphysics/) (and many more).

Comment: Judea Pearl's [Causality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality_(book)) is where I'd start. You may be able to find a PDF of it with a filetype:PDF search. It takes a rigorous statistical approach to modeling causality, addressing practical applications of such models as well as the philosophical and mathematical underpinnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Causality and Scientific Explanation](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=title:%22Causality%20and%20Scientific%20Explanation%22)*** (1972) vol.

1. [*Medieval and Early Classical Science*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4175)
2. [*Classical and Contemporary Science*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7790)

by the historian and philosopher of science and Galileo expert [William A. Wallace, O.P.](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=authors:%22%3DWallace%2C%20William%20A.%2C%20O.P.%22) are [magisterial](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/magisterial#English).

Comment: Answers should not throw references at us. They should give relevant excerpts in plain text as quotes and explain why they are relevant.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Isn't that what [reference-request]-tagged questions are looking for?

Comment: You should give references, yes. But they should be given in a manner that refers to the question text and include relevant quotes in order to explain their relevance. The fact that [links should be contextualised](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) remains true regardless of the type of question.